# How would a Search API microservice fit in an event driven architecture?

Tags: microservices, apache-kafka, event-handling

I apologize if this sounds really strange. I am very new to System Design and have just been reading up on Event driven systems. To gain better understanding and to perfect my thought process I decided to try my hand at designing a very simple version of a food ordering/delivery system (like an Uber Eats). What I have explained below is just a subset of the whole system and for just a handful of users.

My original design was to have a message broker like Kafka in the middle and having Order, Payments, Restaurant, Notification microservices all consuming events from it. The Restaurant microservice would be responsible for all restaurant related actions such as accept customer orders, update customer orders, etc. I also wanted this microservice to be in charge of operations such as adding a new restaurant, updating a restaurant, etc. And here's where I am facing a problem.

When the user decides to search for "Mexican", I want this query to be directed to a SEARCH microservice which would query the Restaurant database and return the results. However, since the rest of the microservices use events to communicate with each other, can this SEARCH microservice bypass the Restaurant microservice and directly query the Restaurant database? Would this be an acceptable design? Or should I scrap the message broker design entirely and design something which communicates via REST calls?

Answer (score 4):

> When the user decides to search for "Mexican", I want this query to be directed to a SEARCH microservice which would query the Restaurant database and return the results.

This design goes against the principle of microservices that each service only has access to its own database. If information from other services is needed, then that should be requested through an API or the service needs to mirror the information in its own database.

Using an API to request information from another service does not mean you can't use a message broker as well to pass events where that is more appropriate.

However, if this `Search` service *always* needs to get information from the `Restaurant` service (or it needs a nearly complete duplicate of the `Restaurant` database) in order to do its job, then your decision to make it a separate service is highly questionable. It looks more like it should actually be part of the `Restaurant` service.

Comment: Thank for you this! Do you think it would be a better idea to instead break up the Restaurant database into say `RESTAURANT_ORDERS` and a `RESTAURANT` where the `Restaurant` microservice talks to only the former and the `SEARCH` works with only the latter?

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to arrive at is, how do I keep the `SEARCH` microservice separate from the entire "place-the-order" process while not violating the principles of system design.

Comment: @Saturnian, what does the `Orders` microservice do if it isn't the "place-the-order" process?

Comment: My bad, I meant "process-the-order" workflow - the entire workflow from when the user places the request till it it delivered to him. `Orders` microservice commits to the `orders` db.

Comment: @Saturnian, I still think you are trying to create too many services and allocating their responsibilities incorrectly. Try a few scenario's out with pen and paper to see what information needs to be exchanged between services and try to keep that to a minimum.

Comment: Perhaps you're right - I'll re-do my design - thank you so much! :)